# increase variable value until condition is met C#

Tags: c#

Can't figure the good logic here I need to increase the value of my counter until the condition is met. but it says that the program is doing nothing here

```
int num;
int ctr = 3;
reqID = browser.Div(Find.ByClass("gwt-Label WNII") && Find.ByIndex(ctr)).OuterText;
bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(reqID, out num);
bool isTR = reqID.Contains("T_R_");

do { ctr++; }
while (isTR == true || isNumeric == true);
{
    reqID = browser.Div(Find.ByClass("gwt-Label WNII") && Find.ByIndex(ctr)).OuterText;
}
```

Parsing this pages

https://hpe.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/Jobsathpe/job/CBC01---Aruba-Cork-CBC01/Pricing-Specialist_1006905-3

https://hpe.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/Jobsathpe/job/RYA01---Riyadh-Al-Faisaliah-Tower-RYA01/Portfolio-Sales-Specialist_1006892-1

See how many iterates of "gwt-Label WNII" class it has

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't switch the `do while` with a simple `for` loop?

Comment: because the increment value is dynamic there is no definite count for it, as per item has different counter.

Comment: You are not changing any of the variables that are your conditions inside the loop. So, the loop will either never start or never finish.

Comment: Your loop is forever

Comment: I notice that also, I'm not familiar with do while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing any of the variables that are your conditions inside the loop. So, the loop will either never start or never finish

You may want to order it like this:

```
int num;
int ctr = 3;

bool isTR = false;
bool IsNumeric = false;

do
{
    reqID = browser.Div(Find.ByClass("gwt-Label WNII") && Find.ByIndex(ctr)).OuterText;
    if(reqID != null)
    {
        isNumeric = int.TryParse(reqID, out num);
        isTR = reqID.Contains("T_R_");
    }
    ctr++;
}
while (!isTR && !isNumeric);
```

`do` reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do

Comment: sorry, try now. Bit quick with the cut and paste!

Comment: gives me Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on contains isTR

Comment: in which case, `browser.Div(Find.ByClass(...)...)` returned null. I'll add a check in.

Comment: what do you want to do if it cannot find what it is looking for? go round loop again or exit?

Comment: i need to loop again it cant be empty and that's why I'm using index because there are tons of same class on the page

Comment: added the "fix", but this loop looks really bad now, it can be infinite!!

Comment: I assume you are looking for "TR" or a number and you want loop until one or other is found?

Comment: Yes that's true that's what I need Here are the sample page im parsing added onto my post

Comment: yes it working but I'm getting the wrong data. I'm getting those Full time posted today and locations

Comment: I believe that you're initial question has been answered, so can I suggest that you mark it as answered and post another question describing your "new" problem, as the answer (whatever it may be) to your new problem doesn't fit this question.

Comment: Sorry but I have another issue "Could not find DIV element tag matching criteria: 'Attribute 'className' equals 'gwt-Label WNII'' And 'Index = 5' at " can we reset the counter? whe I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Declare your bool outside of you while context and modify it inside :

```
int num;
int ctr = 3;
bool isNumeric = true;
bool isTR = true;

do
{
   reqID = browser.Div(Find.ByClass("gwt-Label WNII") && 
   Find.ByIndex(ctr)).OuterText;
   isNumeric = int.TryParse(reqID, out num);
   isTR = reqID.Contains("T_R_");
   ctr++;
}
while (isTR == true || isNumeric == true);
```

Comment: It gives me error on bool isTR " Object reference not set to an instance of an object"